# getting Unknown query pipeline: name or id SearchResults

Tags: coveo

I have installed coveo 5.x version in Sitecore 10.3 and completed all the initial setup and rebuild index as well. When I click in page level search button getting below exception.

```
   ERROR A "Bad Request" error was detected when getting the response from Coveo. Response Content:
{
  "statusCode" : 400,
  "message" : "Unknown query pipeline: name or id \"SearchResults\"",
  "type" : "UnknownQueryPipelineOtherException",
  "executionReport" : [ {
    "children" : [ {
      "name" : "RequestId",
      "description" : "The id correlating logs for this request",
      "duration" : 0,
      "X-Request-ID" : "XXXX"
    }, {
      "name" : "Organization ID",
      "description" : "Organization ID",
      "duration" : 0,
      "coveo_organization" : "xxxxxxxx"
    }, {
      "name" : "PerformAuthentication",
      "description" : "Perform authentication",
      "duration" : 0,
      "configured" : {
        "primary" : "CloudToken"
      },
      "result" : {
        "userIds" : [ {
          "name" : "anonymous",
          "kind" : "User",
          "provider" : "Email Security Provider",
          "infos" : { }
        } ],
        "roles" : [ "queryExecutor" ],
        "queryRestrictions" : { },
        "userGroups" : [ ]
      },
      "children" : [ {
        "name" : "ResolveProviderAuthentication",
        "description" : "Resolve authentication of provider: CloudToken",
        "duration" : 0,
        "result" : {
          "userIds" : [ {
            "name" : "anonymous",
            "kind" : "User",
            "provider" : "Email Security Provider",
            "infos" : { }
          } ],
          "roles" : [ "queryExecutor" ],
          "queryRestrictions" : { },
          "userGroups" : [ ]
        }
      } ]
    }, {
      "name" : "PerformAuthentication",
      "description" : "Perform authentication",
      "duration" : 0,
      "configured" : {
        "secondary" : [ "sso" ],
        "mandatory" : [ ]
      },
      "result" : {
        "userIds" : [ {
          "name" : "anonymous",
          "kind" : "User",
          "provider" : "Email Security Provider",
          "infos" : { }
        } ],
        "roles" : [ "queryExecutor" ],
        "queryRestrictions" : { },
        "userGroups" : [ ]
      },
      "children" : [ {
        "name" : "MergeAuthentications",
        "description" : "Merge authentications (if needed)",
        "duration" : 0,
        "result" : {
          "userIds" : [ {
            "name" : "anonymous",
            "kind" : "User",
            "provider" : "Email Security Provider",
            "infos" : { }
          } ],
          "roles" : [ "queryExecutor" ],
          "queryRestrictions" : { },
          "userGroups" : [ ]
        }
      } ]
    }, {
      "name" : "ResolveContext",
      "description" : "Resolve context",
      "duration" : 2,
      "result" : {
        "userAgent" : {
          "raw" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
          "browser" : [ "chrome" ],
          "device" : [ "desktop", "pc", "windows" ],
          "os" : [ "windows" ]
        },
        "searchHub" : "search",
        "tab" : null,
        "referrer" : "https://sitecoreurl/",
        "locale" : "en",
        "context" : { },
        "expressions" : {
          "q" : {
            "original" : "",
            "parsed" : null
          },
          "aq" : {
            "original" : "((((@dynewcontenttype<>unknown (@z95xpath<>e036c4a9203e4ebbafd775c6bdd44045 (@z95xpath<>172bf9048ca04510bf40c34af25b0ae3 @z95xpath<>9ae86ed349f7459684830161f7b91a4a))) OR @dynewcontenttype==FAQs) OR @source==\"ATCC-CH\") NOT @z95xtemplate==(ADB6CA4F03EF4F47B9AC9CE2BA53FF97,FE5DD82648C6436DB87A7C4210C7413B))",
            "parsed" : "((((@dynewcontenttype<>unknown (@z95xpath<>e036c4a9203e4ebbafd775c6bdd44045 (@z95xpath<>172bf9048ca04510bf40c34af25b0ae3 @z95xpath<>9ae86ed349f7459684830161f7b91a4a))) OR @dynewcontenttype==FAQs) OR @source==\"ATCC-CH\") NOT @z95xtemplate==(ADB6CA4F03EF4F47B9AC9CE2BA53FF97,FE5DD82648C6436DB87A7C4210C7413B))"
          },
          "cq" : {
            "original" : "((@z95xlanguage==en) (@z95xlatestversion==1) (@source==\"Coveo_web_index - ATCC-INTDEV-103\")) OR (@source==(CRMQA,\"ATCC-CH\"))",
            "parsed" : "((@z95xlanguage==en) (@z95xlatestversion==1) (@source==\"Coveo_web_index - ATCC-INTDEV-103\")) OR (@source==(CRMQA,\"ATCC-CH\"))"
          },
          "dq" : {
            "original" : "",
            "parsed" : null
          },
          "lq" : {
            "original" : "",
            "parsed" : null
          }
        },
        "enableDuplicateFiltering" : false,
        "filterField" : null,
        "filterFieldRange" : 5,
        "parentField" : null,
        "childField" : null,
        "recommendation" : null,
        "lowercaseOperators" : false,
        "sortCriteria" : [ "relevancy" ]
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "ResolvePipeline",
      "description" : "Resolve pipeline",
      "error" : "Unknown query pipeline: name or id \"SearchResults\""
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

I found one article related to my issues but I dont know where to check whether i have given pipeline or not.
https://connect.coveo.com/s/article/6892
could someone help me here

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and fixed it.
Root cause:: you do not have the **SearchResults** query pipeline.
Fix:: So please add a new pipeline by duplicating the existing default pipeline in the coveo cloud platform. Or else corect the pipeline name in Coveo settings in sitecore.